# Como chamar uma função javascript de um arquivos externo?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Estou com problemas para validar um campo ao clicar no botão `incluir`, assim que eu clico em `incluir` dá esse erro abaixo:

> **Não é possível obter valor da propriedade 'value': o objeto é
>   nulo ou não definido.**

Esse erro aparece nessa linha da função:

`(document.getElementById("<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>").value == "")`

O arquivo onde contém a função já foi instanciado no código html:

```
<script src="Javascript/validacao.js" type = "text/javascript" > < /script>
```

Code view onde contém o `incluir_click` e seu `Page_Load` retornando a função js:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    btnIncluir.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return valida_campos()")
End Sub
```

Função de validação de e-mail no arquivo .js:

```js
    function valida_campos() {

      if (document.getElementById("<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>").value == "") {
        alert("Email obrigatório");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
      }

      var emailPat = /^(\".*\"|[0-9-A-Za-z]\w*)@(\[\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}]|[A-Za-z]\w*(\.[A-Za-z]\w*)+)$/;
      var emailid = document.getElementById("<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>").value;
      var matchArray = emailid.match(emailPat);
      if (matchArray == null) {
        alert("O Email esta no formato incorreto. Tente novamente.");
        document.getElementById("<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>").focus();
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Retire o `<%= %>`.

O `<%=` pega elementos que sejam do Servidor.

Se sua função Javascript estivesse diratamente na página ela funcionaria.

Coloque dessa forma e irá funcionar:

```
(document.getElementById("txtEmail").value == "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Para chamar o ID de um componente .NET via javascript é necessário setar o atributo ClientIDMode na criação do componente para "Static":

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNmBanco" Width="140px" MaxLength="80" ClientIDMode="Static" TabIndex="2"  placeholder="Nome do Banco" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Dessa forma você pode localiza-lo através do JS usando o ID direto:

```
document.getElementById('txtNumBanco');
```

No entanto, a forma como você fez também deve funcionar, tenho um codigo que valida email digitado da seguinte forma:

```
var txtEmail = document.getElementById('<%= Email.ClientID %>');
```

E a declaração do componente está assim:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" Width="250px" MaxLength="100" TabIndex="6" onblur="javascript: return ValidaEmail();"
                        ToolTip="Escreva um email que você use com frequência"></asp:TextBox>
```

Ao abrir a página no browser verifique através do Inspetor de Elementos do seu navegador, qual o ID que foi gerado, se estiver apenas como `ID="txtEmail"` então pode acessar direto:

```
var valor = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
```

Uma ótima fonte sobre o funcionamento do ClientID: [ClientIDMode in ASP.NET 4.0](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40)

Até